# Dollar Signs in Javascript Frameworks

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

In jQuery, mooTools, Prototype.js and other JavaScript frameworks, it is common to use the dollar sign as an element selector. It selects the DOM node and applies the framework to it.

**I hate this.**

As a programmer, "$" means nothing to me. In jQuery, you can replace the dollar sign with just that:

`$('#divID')` is the same thing as `jQuery('#divID')` which I find much more explicit.

I have had trouble, however, finding whether other frameworks support similar alternate notations.

mooTools has `$` and `$$`, and Prototype also uses `$`. Does anyone know what function (if any) replaces these?

Comment: `var prototype = $`. Now go wild.

Comment: *$* = *S* for Select?  `$` is one keystroke, which I think is why people like it.

Comment: $ is a simple, open, and valid variable name, which is why it is used. It certainly is one keystroke, but there is a good reason why programmers are discouraged from using single-letter variable and function names.

Answer (score 2):

If you want another name for the functionality, just assign one, like this

```
var myName = $;
```

Then the whole functionality becomes available by this new `myName`.

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't solve conflicts. For example, if I do

var myName = $; am I naming the prototype, mootools, or jQuery functions?

Comment: @omniuni Your're naming whatever currently holds that variable. If you want to use multiple frameworks, load them one by one and assign the new names before loading the next one.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a **valid** javascript variable.

Anything could be assigned to it!

For example:

```
$ = 42;

//or
$ = jQuery;
```

`$` is just the variable that many javascript libraries use to store their `init` function.

---

So, since now you know that `$` can be a function (when it comes to many libraries) you can assign `$` to any other variable as well:

```
var newVar = $;
```

Comment: I think you mis-read the question. He seems to be asking how you can use a function name other than `$` to refer to Prototype/ mooTools (like jQuery offers `jQuery`).

Comment: @Matt hmmm yea, that is what it seems... I added to my answer to better conform to the OP, but also explain why and how `$` can be used.

Comment: More specifically, I am asking if the other frameworks have, like jQuery, a built-in specific function name. I have come across some situations where multiple frameworks are in use, or where it would be useful if multiple frameworks could be used, and having $ used as the primary function name in all of them makes things rather confusing. Thank you for the answer, though.